# Should i sanitize $_POST in WP Query?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the WP Query:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => $_POST['type']
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Should I sanitize $_POST['data'] in the WP_Query. And how i can do that?

Comment: $_POST should ALWAYS be sanitized, regardless of the CMS/framework you use. Never trust the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [WPCS](https://developer.wordpress.org/coding-standards/wordpress-coding-standards/), you have to sanitize the data

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => isset( $_POST['type'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_POST['type'] ) ) : '',
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```